# L-BFGS-B in cpp?

Tags: optimization, constraint

I know I am not supposed to ask for resources, but I couldn't find any resource and am sure there must be something out there: Is there a **cpp** implementation of the L-BFGS-B optimization available somewhere? I could find an implementation of L-BFGS, [here](http://www.loshchilov.com/pbfgs.html).